# How to build Qt 5.5 with QtScript

Tags: qt, configure

QtScript module was deprecated in Qt 5.5, but they claimed, that it can be built from sources. Do you know, how to do it?
I tried

```
./configure -script <..>
./configure -qtscript <..>
./configure -feature-script <..>
./configure -feature-qtscript <..>
```

ect, finaly, just configured

```
./configure <..>
jom.exe all
```

But there are no QtScript binaries, as expected. I tried

```
jom.exe script
jom.exe qtscript
```

without any success. I can't find, how to include some module...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't it deprecated in 5.5?

Comment: It is, but I have an old project, which uses QtScript. So untill Qt6 it should be possible to build it manualy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally, I figured out how to do it. The target name is

```
module-qtscript
```

So, it looks like

```
jom.exe module-qtscript
```

Comment: Just for memorizing: jom.exe module-qtscript will build QtScript, but to install it, you have to change directory: cd qtscrtipt; jom.exe install